# Is there a tool for converting the Emma XML reports to Cobertura XML format?

Tags: xml, code-coverage, cobertura, emma, gcov

I am using a code coverage tool that can only generate Emma XML report, while what I need is Cobertura or gcov format. Does there already exist some tool for doing the conversion? If not, I'm afraid I must do it myself.

Comment: Did you do it? I am looking for the same thing.

Comment: Definitely being interesting in that as well. Getting emma coverage out of Android integration tests is easy, now I just have to "marry" those with the cobertura results of the JUnit tests...

Comment: I could not find anything out there that does this. Would be great if someone knows of something.

Answer (score -2):

[cover2cover](https://github.com/rix0rrr/cover2cover) has been created for this purpose.

Comment: I think that's for JaCoCo, not Emma.